# calling PriceBookEntry from Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, remote-objects, pricebookentry

After reading tons of links, posts and many documents, I decided to ask for help here, hopping some guru can help me with this issue:

```
<!-- Visualforce Remote object component for Products -->
<apex:remoteObjects >
<apex:remoteObjectModel name="PriceBookEntry" jsShorthand="Prod" fields="id, Name, Pricebook2Id, UnitPrice, IsActive">
</apex:remoteObjectModel>
</apex:remoteObjects>
```

I have done this javascript fuction to display records from PriceBookEntry Object using remoteObject in Javascript:

```
function fetchPB(){var wh = new SObjectModel.Prod();
wh.retrieve({
  where:{
        Pricebook2Id : {eq:'01so0000002r3TBAAY'}, 
        IsActive : {eq:true},
        UnitPrice : {gt: 0}
  },
  limit: 5
  },function(err, records){
    if(err) alert(err.message);
    else {
      records.forEach(function(record) {             
        var divCol = $('<div class="row">');
        var p = record.get("Pricebook2Id");
        alert('row => ' + record.toString());
        var detail = $('<p>'+record.get("Name")+'<br/></p>');           
        var link1 = $('<p><br/><input type="check" name="optCheck"></p> ');
        link1.click(function(){              
          $('#inputProduct2').val(record.get("UnitPrice"));
        });
        detail.append(link1);
        h3.append(detail); 
        divCol.append(product);
        divCol.appendTo('#prodRow');
      });
    }
  });
```

}

When I execute this function I can see in the developer console of my browser the post action and the data is coming from the server
[image]

Even I see the data is coming I can't get the object's values, if I display a javascript alert with the object information I can't see values only this:

[image]

Comment: thats the reason I don't like js alert() for debugging. Use `console.log('---here---',record.toString());` open browser console and check the result.

Comment: it display the same:
---here---[object Object]

Comment: Can you just remove the tostring()  try like this `console.log('---here---',record);`.. check this is returning JS object or not.

Comment: Nothing get displayed

Comment: what you can see in browser console ?

Comment: I get this:

---here---[object Object]
---here---[object Object]
---here---[object Object]
---here---[object Object]
---here---[object Object]

Comment: I added:
console.log('---here---' + JSON.stringify(record));

And got this:

---here---{"_name":"PriceBookEntry","_fields":{"Pricebook2Id":{"type":"Y"},"UnitPrice":{"type":"C"},"id":{"type":"Y"},"IsActive":{"type":"B"},"Name":{"type":"S"}},"_fieldShorthands":{},"_props":{}}
---here---{"_name":"PriceBookEntry","_fields":{"Pricebook2Id":{"type":"Y"},"UnitPrice":{"type":"C"},"id":{"type":"Y"},"IsActive":{"type":"B"},"Name":{"type":"S"}},"_fieldShorthands":{},"_props":{}}

Note there are no values but :{"type":"C"},"

Comment: Yes you need to convert into JSON using `JSON.stringify(record)`

Comment: I just did that 
 
I added: console.log('---here---' + JSON.stringify(record));
and I get this:
---here---{"_name":"PriceBookEntry","_fields":{"Pricebook2Id":{"type":"Y"},"Unit‌​Price":{"type":"C"},"id":{"type":"Y"},"IsActive":{"type":"B"},"Name":{"type":"S"}‌​},"_fieldShorthands":{},"_props":{}} ---here---{"_name":"PriceBookEntry","_fields":{"Pricebook2Id":{"type":"Y"},"Unit‌​Price":{"type":"C"},"id":{"type":"Y"},"IsActive":{"type":"B"},"Name":{"type":"S"}‌​},"_fieldShorthands":{},"_props":{}}

Comment: User. yes you got the all pricebook records what else you are looking for ?

Comment: it's tha even I get all the pricebook records the values are not coming, note the instead of values I get : Unit‌​‌​Price":{"type":"C"}, and a Type S,Y, B for each other field where I should get : {"Pricebook2Id":"01so0000002r3TBAAY","UnitPrice":38.0,"Id":"01uo0000000rd50AAA","IsActive":true,"Name":"Toy Dog - Short Hair"},

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a different approach and get the solution to this tricky salesforce Object. instead of using Javascript Remote Object I used:

`

$(document).ready(function() {
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}"; //Used for Session out
//var queryResult = sforce.connection.query("Select id, Pricebook2Id, Name, UnitPrice, IsActive from PricebookEntry Where Pricebook2Id='01so0000002r3TBAAY' and UnitPrice > 0 and IsActive=TRUE");
var queryResult = sforce.connection.query("Select id, Pricebook2Id, Name, UnitPrice from PricebookEntry Where Pricebook2Id='01so0000002r3TBAAY' and UnitPrice > 0 and IsActive=TRUE");
var records = queryResult.getArray('records');
    var table= $('#example').DataTable( {
        "bPaginate": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bAutoWidth": true,       
        data: records,
        columns: [
           { data: "Name" },
           { data: "UnitPrice" }, {
            "targets": -1,
            "data": "null",
            "defaultContent": "" }
        ]
    } );
     $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row(this).data();
        alert( 'You Choose the Product: '+ data["Id"]);
    } );


} );


var filteredData = table
    .column( 1 )
    .data()
    .filter( function ( value, index ) {
        return value > 20 ? true : false;
    } );

Name
                UnitPrice

```
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>              
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>UnitPrice</th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

---

`